# Jmter-Sampler type not printed in result JTL file

Tags: jmeter

In our jmeter result jtl file I need sampler type, as we have different SLA based on sampler (java request, HTTP request, JDBC request).

Is there is a way we can print the sampler type in JTL file?
Currently even I did all changes in jmeter.properties still not getting sampler type.

Comment: can you modify your answer to add the changes you did to the jmeter properties. It might prove useful for people trying to answer your question

Comment: documentation does not say about any changes in jmeter.properites , i m curious if any body has done the above .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add custom column to your jtl by using [sample_variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) .

Add a line in `user.properties`:

```
sample_variables=type
```

It'll save a type column that will save the `type` variable that you can set before each sampler using [User Parameters](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Parameters)

Comment: @thanks it work ,but this is again manual ,can this would be automated as i dont want users to define what kind of sampler type selected in the JMX .

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) to your Test Plan
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   vars.put('type', prev.getClass().getSimpleName())
   ```
3. Add the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   sample_variable=type
   ```
4. Restart JMeter to pick the change up

Next time you [run your test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) like 
    jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl

you will see an extra column in the `result.jtl` file called `type` and holding the class name of the sampler being executed.